# create database with coding and set username and password for it

Tags: c#, sql-server

i want to create database with code and i want to set username and password for ithow can do it??

```
mysqlcommand = create database[test] on...........
```

Comment: Can you provide more information - e.g. are you using a specific library or API to access SQL Server already?

Comment: SQL Server databases don't have a "username and password" on them to protect access - that's MS-Access thinking, doesnt' work that way in SQL Server. Also: I would **not** create a full database in an application - do this separately, during install.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look into sqlite? It's a standalone relational database, that has all your old favorites from sql wrapped up in one tiny file. It's very mobile.

http://www.sqlite.org/